# ADO Connection to Firebird stays connected

Tags: delphi, database-connection, ado, firebird

I've noticed that ADO Connections to our FireBird 2.1 Server stays open. The connections are initiated from an Intraweb Application in the UserSession Unit.

I use `ADOConnection.Connected := False;` but that does not seem to close the connection. I've also tried `ADOConnection.Close;`.

Is there a way to ensure that an ADO Connection is closed?

Thanks, Pieter.Blockquote

Comment: Thank you for the answers. It Transpires that I did have a connection that was created in a class and not being closed. Everything is now back to normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that IW is using that exactly TADOConnection object?
Or a new connection object is being created behind-the-scenes and you forgot to clean it?

Comment: (to add to that) Can you see the connection count? If so, make sure that you get exactly one new connection when the program starts. And that the extra connection goes away when the program is shut down. We make a lot of ADO connections from our app and have not had this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to free and recreate TADOConnection object.